# Extraer caracteres de una cadena y guardarlos en otra variable usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, string, funciones, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo el siguiente dilema.

Me están solicitando un programa en el cual pueda convertir medidas de cm a mm, mm a pulgadas y pulgadas a cm (para iniciar con la aplicación).

En el ejemplo que me están planteando, necesito convertir un valor de pulgadas, que incluye fracciones, pasarlo a su equivalente en milímetros.

Ingresar en un textbox una medida como esta 35 8/16 pulg. y obtener su equivalencia a mm.

Mi lógica me dice, separar la cadena de caracteres y hacer las multiplicaciones por cada componente, que sería:

35 *25.4

8/16 = (.5)*(25.4)

Mi problema principal es como "desarmar" el valor inicial, que seria 35 8/16, para poder hacer la conversión, y que funciones en Javascript puedo usar para separar las cadenas.

Por el momento no pido código porque quiero tratar de hacerlo por mi mismo, solo su asesoria de como podria hacerse el proceso y que funciones podría usar para extraer las cadenas de caracteres.

Gracias Comunidad.

Comment: Usando usando [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) podes empezar separando la cadena por espacio, para obtener la parte entera y la facción. Luego la fracción la separas por `/`.

Comment: Pero, no entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Dices que esto `35 8/16` es un valor en pulgadas? ¿? Tradúcelo, porque no lo entiendo. ¿Cuántas pulgadas es eso?

Comment: @A.Cedano: Son 35 pulgadas y media (hubiese sido mejor que tuviera 7/16 para justificar el uso de los dieciseisavos).

Comment: @A.Cedano: el valor puede cambiar, por ejemplo, me dicen que podría ser 35 8/16, o bien 75 13/16 o 26 3/8; desconozco porque usan los valores así, pero me mostraron un ejercicio, y en efecto, cuando captura el valor asi, les da la equilavencia ya sea en cm o en mm.

Comment: Como lo mencionaba en mi post original, lo que hacen es dividir numerador entre denominador, y el resultado lo multiplican por 25.4 que es lo que vale 1 pulg en milimetros.
 y ese resultado lo suman a la operacion del entero por 25.4 y con eso ya obtienen el valor en milimetros.
8 / 16 = (.5) * (25.4) = 12.7
35 * 25.4 = 889
889 + 12.7 = 901.7 mm

Comment: Pues intenta hacerlo con `split` y si tienes problemas nos dices, agregando el código que tengas escrito.

Comment: Hola Comunidad.

Solo para pasar a comentar que el split me funcionó muy bien; gracias por sus comentarios, si me surge alguna duda estaré pasando por estos rumbos de nuevo. Feliz Fin De Semana.

Comment: Bienvenido. Esto no es un foro. Para evitar tantos comentarios sugiero que adaptes la pregunta a ¿Cómo puedo separar la cadena `35 8/16` en un arreglo como `["35", "8/16"]`?. De paso se puede responder mejor o marcar duplicado y que no quede sin respuesta. ¿Por cierto, la pregunta es de Javascript o C#?

Comment: Hola, está todo muy lindo, pero así como está, solo va a funcionar con valores tipo "x" pulgadas y media, si te llegan a pasar "1 3/4" tu resultado va a ser erróneo, para calcular los milímetros usas "**( 25.4 * 35 ) +( ( 25.4 * 8 ) / 16 )**" , los paréntesis no son necesarios, solo los pongo porque me parece que queda más claro cual es la operación.

Comment: creo que haca ya respondieron lo que quieres hacer .... [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342202/buscar-un-caracter-en-una-cadena-de-texto-crear-array-y-dar-un-valor-aleatorio)